# WSO2AM 2.1.0-update12 loosing code grant, silent error updating an application

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Having WSO2AM 2.1.0-update12 (with mysql) with following use case

- in the API Store we crete an application
- assign code grant permission with a callback url
- save
- edit application

Updating the application keys will fail anyway (this stack is from using the default h2 database)

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement " SELECT    AKM.CONSUMER_KEY  FROM    AM_APPLICATION APP,   AM_APPLICATION_KEY_MAPPING AKM,   AM_SUBSCRIBER SUB  WHERE    SUB.SUBSCRIBER_ID=APP.SUBSCRIBER_ID    AND APP.APPLICATION_ID = AKM.APPLICATION_ID    AND APP.NAME = ? AND AKM.KEY_TYPE=?   AND  ( (APP.APPLICATION_ID IN (SELECT APPLICATION_ID  FROM AM_APPLICATION_GROUP_MAPPING WHERE GROUP_ID IN ($PARAMS[*]) AND TENANT = ?))  OR  LOWER(SUB.USER_ID) = ?) "; expected "[, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )"; SQL statement:
 SELECT    AKM.CONSUMER_KEY  FROM    AM_APPLICATION APP,   AM_APPLICATION_KEY_MAPPING AKM,   AM_SUBSCRIBER SUB  WHERE    SUB.SUBSCRIBER_ID=APP.SUBSCRIBER_ID    AND APP.APPLICATION_ID = AKM.APPLICATION_ID    AND APP.NAME = ? AND AKM.KEY_TYPE=?   AND  ( (APP.APPLICATION_ID IN (SELECT APPLICATION_ID  FROM AM_APPLICATION_GROUP_MAPPING WHERE GROUP_ID IN ($params) AND TENANT = ?))  OR  lower(SUB.USER_ID) = ?) [42001-175]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
```

- set a visibility group and save

now the application seems to be working, but the code grant is "unchecked" and it is not possible to set it again

```
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error when reading the application information from the persistence store.
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.handleException(ApiMgtDAO.java:6399)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getConsumerKeyForApplicationKeyType(ApiMgtDAO.java:4799)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.updateAuthClient(APIConsumerImpl.java:3313)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.updateAuthClient(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:34)
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (9 > number of parameters, which is 4).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
```

Is there any way to work around or compensate? (not to loose the code grant)

Note: we've created a few extensions (userstore manager, group extractor, AuthorizationHandler) and some are not compatible with newer versions

Comment: Please check in 2.2.0

Comment: @Bee: for that we will need to rewrite our customizations :/ But if it's needed, the client will need to set the path